# Find the solution of $Ax=b$.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, numerical-methods, numerical-linear-algebra

Construct a perturbation $\Delta b$ of the right hand side for which we have

$$\frac{||\Delta x||}{||x||} \geq 10^8 \frac{||\Delta b||}{||b||}$$

where $x+\Delta x$ is the solution to $A(x+ \Delta x)=b+\Delta b$

$$A=
\begin{bmatrix}
1+10^{-8} & 1 \\
1 & 1 \\
\end{bmatrix}$$

$$A^{-1}= 10^8
\begin{bmatrix}
 1 & -1 \\
 -1 & 1+10^{-8} \\
\end{bmatrix}$$

$$b=
\begin{bmatrix}
 1 \\
 1 \\
\end{bmatrix}$$

Solving for $x=A^{-1}b$. I got 
$x=
\begin{bmatrix}
 0 \\
 1 \\
\end{bmatrix}$.
Now solving for $\Delta x$ using $\frac{||\Delta x||}{||x||} \geq 10^8 \frac{||\Delta b||}{||b||}$ I got the system,

\begin{array}{lcl} 
\Delta x_1  & = & 10^8\Delta b_1 - 10^8\Delta b_2 \\
\Delta x_2  & = & -10^8\Delta b_1 + (10^8+1)\Delta b_2 \\
\end{array}

How do I proceed?

Comment: Try $Δb=ε(1,0)$ or $ε(1,-1)$ or ... anything perpendicular to $(1,1)$.

Comment: Use the condition on the relative error (the one with the norms) to get some easy linear inequalities on $ \Delta b_1$ and $ \Delta b_2$ then choose any $\Delta b$ satisfying those inequalities.